# How pass custom property in scss' function or mixin?

Tags: sass

I would directly pass property name in my scss' as an a argument of function or mixin. 
So far I fail to pass a property name as argument.

Here my code:

```
@mixin buttonSide($buttonSide){
    $buttonSide:10vw;
}


.form__previous-button{
    @include buttonSide(left); // I have also tried with @include buttonSide("left")
}
```

So far it fails. Do you know a way to pass a property as a variable in scss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [interpolation on property declarations](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations#interpolation) to solve this:

> A property's name can include interpolation, which makes it possible to dynamically generate properties as needed. You can even interpolate the entire property name!

**SASS**

```
@mixin buttonSide($buttonSide)
  #{$buttonSide}: 10vw

.form__previous-button
  @include buttonSide(left)
```

**SCSS**

```
@mixin buttonSide($buttonSide) {
  #{$buttonSide}: 10vw;
}

.form__previous-button {
  @include buttonSide(left);
}
```